# AJAX call to load 10 more items doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, dajaxice

I'm trying to load 10 items each time the load more button is clicked. I initially send the first 10 items and use dajaxice to load more 10 items each time the button is pressed.

Here is my view

```
def dj(request, slug):
    dj = DJ.objects.get(slug=slug)
    dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj, duplicate=False).order_by('-votes', '-release_date')[:10]
    return render(request, 'hunt/dj.html', {'dj_song_list': dj_song_list, 'slug': slug, 'dj': dj})
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        Dajaxice.hunt.load_more(Dajax.process, {'items': $("#dj_song_list").find('div').length - 1, 'dj_name': $('.dj_name').text().trim()})
    }
</script>
```

Here is my ajax.py

```
@dajaxice_register
def load_more(request, items, dj_name=None):
    if dj_name:
        dj = DJ.objects.get(name=dj_name)
        dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj, duplicate=False).order_by('-votes', '-release_date')[:items+10]
        render = render_to_string('hunt/dj.html', {'dj_song_list': dj_song_list, 'slug': dj.slug, 'dj': dj.name})
        dajax = Dajax()
        dajax.assign('#edmhunters_body','innerHTML',render)
        return dajax.json()
```

This code loads 10 more songs but the DJ objects is not passed correctly. I get the following error

```
DoesNotExist: DJ matching query does not exist.
```

On investigating I found that slug was printing fine in the ajax call but in the view it was something like `hardwell/hunt/img/.jpg`. It probably has something to do with how the slug is retrieved. Here is my HTML where the slug is retrieved.

```
<a href="{% url 'dj' slug=dj.slug %}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}hunt/img/{{ dj.rank }}.jpg"/></a>
```

Why is the slug appending the string at the end?

I even added a code in the view to trim the extra string of the slug but it still doesn't work as expected. It doesn't throw the `DoesNotExist` error but the DJ object is still not passed.

```
if slug.endswith('/hunt/img/.jpg'):
        slug = slug[:-len('/hunt/img/.jpg')]
```

Here is the view initially loaded

[image: Here is the view initially loaded]

Here is the view after the AJAX call

[image: Here is the view after the AJAX call]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any easier solution to this?

Comment: If your `view` is returning something like `/hunt/img/`, you should not write this path in your HTML since it will be duplicated. Consider this: `{{STATIC_URL}}{{dj.rank}}` This should do the trick.

Comment: @weasel But that this is the path to my img url, so I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

In one method you are using the slug to find the Dj and in the `load_more` you are using the name. You should use dj slug in both and I would use Django pagination to get more items instead of passing the number of found divs.

You can just increment the page parameter send to the load more.

```
@dajaxice_register
def load_more(request, page, dj_slug=None):
    if dj_slug:
        try:
            dj = DJ.objects.get(slug=dj_slug)
        except DJ.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        queryset = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj, duplicate=False).order_by('-votes', '-release_date')
        paginator = Paginator(queryset)

        render = render_to_string('hunt/dj.html', {
            'dj_song_page': paginator.page(page), 
            'slug': dj.slug, 
            'dj': dj.name
        })
        dajax = Dajax()
        dajax.assign('#edmhunters_body','innerHTML', render)
        return dajax.json()
```

The dj_song_page is a page returned by the paginator. It will contain the items for that page. Read more on django docs about pagination here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/

The main problem I think is that you have to use the slug not the name. The queryset must be the same as the one in the `dj` view.

Comment: Using a slug instead of name did not make any difference to the output.

Comment: Passing the slug still doesn't find the DJ?

Comment: The reason why in the new view we have /hunt/img/.jpg is that it didn't find the DJ instance and django templates fail silently outputing an empty string.

Comment: The `DoesNotExist` error is thrown by the views.py file when it's rendered again and not by ajax.py

Comment: Is dajaxice changing the url when you load more?

Comment: No the URL remains the same